# Fails to save model after running GridSearchCV with a scikit pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have the following toy example to replicate the issue

```py
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=30, n_features=5, noise=0.2)

reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(tree_method='hist', eval_metric='mae', n_jobs= 4)
steps = list()
steps.append(('reg', reg))
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
param_grid = {'reg__max_depth': [2, 4, 6],}
cv = 3
model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
best_model = model.fit(X = X, y = y)
```

Then the following four methods fail to save the fitted model:

```py
model.save_model('test_1.json')

# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'save_model'
```

```py
best_model.save_model('test2.json')

# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'save_model'
```

```py
best_model.best_estimator_.save_model('test3.json')

# AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'save_model'
```

```py
model.best_estimator_.save_model('test4.json')

# AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'save_model'
```

But these two methods work.

```py
import joblib
joblib.dump(model.best_estimator_, 'naive_model.joblib')
joblib.dump(best_model.best_estimator_, 'naive_best_model.joblib')
```

Can anyone tell me if it is the way I constructer my pipeline mistakenly breaks the method to save the best model?

Comment: Only "xgboost" object has an attribute "save_model". When you  use gridsearch it is already a different object wrapped around "xgboost". The same thing with pipelines. In case of "gridsearch" you probably may retrieve "xgboost" object by using "best_estimator_".
"joblib" and "pickle" are more universal solutions, imho

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention that you have "pipeline" inside "gridsearch", so you won't be able to extract xgboost object with "best_estimator". You will need to do `model.best_estimator_['reg'].save_model`. But it will save only xgboost without any data transformations in pipeline

Comment: @Thoughtful_monkey's points are correct. Do you want to turn those into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only "xgboost" object has an attribute "save_model". When you use gridsearch it is already a different object wrapped around "xgboost". The same thing with pipelines. You will need to do `model.best_estimator_['reg'].save_model`. But it will save only xgboost without any data transformation from pipeline.
"joblib" and "pickle" are more universal solutions, imho